# JQuery/Javascript - What exactly is the valueCommit event, at what point is it called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've come across this in JQuery:

```
        $("#myHTMLcontrolID").bind('valueCommit', function (e, combo) {
            //function code here
        });
```

It's being used to bind a dropdown so that when an option is selected in the dropdown, Ajax is used to update a linked dropdown.

My question is, would someone please clarify what this event is (like is it a JQuery or AJAX specific event), and what are the immediately preceding and succeeding JavaScript events (e.g. like OnChange)

Comment: [It's a Flex event](https://www.google.ca/search?q=valueCommit).

Comment: That's what this was originally looking like when I Google'd it.  How though can I find out if Flex is definitely being used in the ASP.NET solution I'm working on, and roughly how would the event be working using Flex?

Comment: I'm clearly not putting much thought to this follow-up, but you might find something if you search you entire code base for "flex".

Answer (score 0):

It's a custom JQuery event that just happens to be the name of an Adobe flex built-in event.  See http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-custom-events/ for an explanation of how to create a custom JQuery event

I found the usage of the event in this code in the solution:

```
        $('select').sexyCombo({
            hideListCallback: function () {
                $(this).trigger('valueCommit');
            },
            initEventsCallback: function () {
                $(this).bind('valueCommit', { that: this }, function (e) {
                    var combo = e.data.that;
                    var selectElement = combo.selectbox;
                    $(selectElement).trigger('valueCommit', combo);
                })
            }
        });
```

As to when a JQuery custom event is called in relation to, for example 'onChange', I still don't know